# Find Non-Matching Strings using Application.Match in two arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I found the index of missing arrays using the following function in Excel VBA:

```
absentArr = Application.Match(Data, varrayReference, False)
```

How do I extract the values that are missing in array "Data" when compared with the reference array "varrayReference"?

I can seen the non-matching arrays in the array "absentArray" but I need the corresponding missing IDs that are in the "Data" array (for example Data(18), Data(20) that show non matches in the "'absentArray"). Is there a way to get the missing cells in the "Data" array? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not do the reverse match and store the results in another array or a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use VBA'a Filter if you want a 1:1 match; Filter acts like a wildcard search so positive returns would be found for *123* in *qw123op* and *df123uy*.

Using the worksheet's Match function quickly locates 1:1 matches but are not case sensitive.

```
Sub findMissing()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim data As Variant, absentArray As Variant, missingData As Variant
    Dim dict as object, k as variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    data = Array("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH")
    absentArray = Array("AB", "BC", "DE", "GH")
    ReDim missingData(LBound(data) To UBound(data))

    j = LBound(data)
    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        If IsError(Application.Match(data(i), absentArray, 0)) Then
            'method one with array
            missingData(j) = data(i)
            j = j + 1
            'method two with dictionary
            dict.Item(data(i)) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve missingData(j - 1)

    For i = LBound(missingData) To UBound(missingData)
        Debug.Print missingData(i)
    Next i

    For Each k in dict.Keys
        Debug.Print k
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I am trying to just get unique values in the array missingData. Any inputs?

Comment: Switch the coding to add missing items into a dictionary as the dictionary's keys if you want uniqueness.